# How to draw 2 histograms in 1 table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I was planning to combine these 2 histograms under 1 table. Also, they need to be side by side, i.e., data cannot overlap each other.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

df.hist(column='oq_len', bins = 25, color = 'blue')
df.hist(column='cq_len', bins = 25, color = 'red')
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: tag issue has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), histograms can be combined. `multiple='dodge'` will place the bars for different columns next to each other. `shrink=0.8` will make the bars a bit narrower (default they occupy all available space).

The original plot gives the impression that the values are all integers. The bin edges should take this into account. `sns.histplot`'s `dicrete=True` parameter takes care of that.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cq_len': np.random.geometric(p=0.25, size=500).clip(0, 15),
                   'oq_len': np.random.geometric(p=0.31, size=500).clip(0, 15)})
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, discrete=True, multiple='dodge', shrink=0.8)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.margins(x=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with multiple='dodge']